# Unable to install rosserial on Fuerte

Tags: arduino, ros-fuerte, rosserial, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am currently trying to install rosserial for ROS Fuerte, and I keep getting server time out message after the command hg clone htp://kforge.ros.org/rosserial/hg rosserial.

I've followed the instruction from htp://wiki.ros.org/ rosserial_arduino/ Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup. I'm currently using Raspberry-Pi with Fuerte installed.

I'm a bit new in using Linux and ROS, what should I do ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/130196/unable-to-install-rosserial-on-fuerte/) by [WMHanif](https://answers.ros.org/users/12081/wmhanif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The kforge.ros.org server was shut down a while back when Willow Garage downsized. The rosserial package is now hosted on [github](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial); you can download the fuerte version using:

```
git clone -b fuerte-devel https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial.git
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-02-17**:
It should be noted that the fuerte-devel branch is a bit of a best-effort reconstruction and may not actually represent what the last fuerte release actually was...

**Comment by [WMHanif](https://answers.ros.org/users/12081/wmhanif/) on 2014-02-18**:
thanks, that worked ! but later i got this error ''The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['rosserial_arduino']'' for ''rosmake rosserial_arduino'', any ideas why ?